# Are SMTP mail deliveries always point to point?

Tags: path, smtp

Can I assume that when an email is sent from one domain's SMTP server, that it goes directly to the receiver's domain? Under what circumstances, might it NOT go directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, you can't.

For instance, a SMTP server may be configured to route some or all domains through a relay SMTP server. This is really useful if you own a small-scale SMTP server for your domain and your provider has a well-know one which won't be on any blacklist.

Comment: So, it has some stickiness?  In other words, the receiver could tell from the header if it came directly or not. It probably will continue to be routed that way, but there is no guarantee.  The path could be reconfigured.  Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the receiver can tell from the headers, since every relay will insert a Received header. And yes, the path will probably stay equivalent but there is absolutely no guarantee.